# UISegmentedControl maintain aspect ratio on image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm having a hard time making images on a UISegmentedControl keep their aspect ratio and not scale to all sides.
Here's what it looks like:
[image: UiSegmentedControl maintain aspect ratio]

The images are 100X100(except nr 6 gonna replace soon) and I want them to maintain the aspect ratio.

I have tried:

```
self.segment.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
//and:
self.segment.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
```

Are there a way I can target the UIImageView in the segment..that way I can set the contentMode..right? Or is there another approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
segmentedControl.subviews.flatMap{$0.subviews}.forEach { subview in
    if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView, let image = imageView.image, image.size.width > 5 {
        // The imageView which isn't separator
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: This is the **only** solution of found that actually works reliably. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out when (i.e., where in code) to execute it. I have a UISegmentedControl subclass, and tried putting it in awakeFromNib, but it didn't work. I also have a target action on .valueChanged, and when I handle it there it works. So there's something about the order of (re)drawing that clearly makes a difference. In my case, it's in a table view cell, so perhaps a layoutSubviews is running?

Comment: We decided to simply use a stack view with buttons

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's a great, general purpose solution for this:

```
UIImageView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

This uses the approach described here: [UIImageView.appearance is overriding UISegmentedControl.appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062659/uiimageview-appearance-is-overriding-uisegmentedcontrol-appearance)

In my case, I constrained it to a subclass of UISegmentedControl (in case I want the default aspectFill for other situations).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to set the contentMode to ScaleAspectFit but you can use the following code to set a margin around your image when you are setting the image :

```
yourSegmentedControl.setImage(yourImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: .init(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10), resizingMode: .stretch), forSegmentAt: 0)
```

You can change the values of "top", "left", "bottom" and "right" as you want.
This worked for me, I hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably late for this, but Im sure it will help someone.

My **Problem #1**:
Images in the segmented control are distorted in ratio.

My **Problem #2**:
You can't even change the colour of the image. It remains black. Even if you use .alwaysTemplate and imageview tint colour. It wont budge.

**Solution**:
Forget trying to hack the SDK, or achieving the goal through unofficial means. Apple can easily change the SegmentedControl and all your work becomes redundant.
Use this instead: [BetterSegmentedControl](https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl). Happy coding.

It is highly customisable and easy to use, plus it supports images.