# UIImageView.appearance is overriding UISegmentedControl.appearance

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uisegmentedcontrol

I've been trying to use the appearance proxy API to apply some default colors to some controls, but I've run into a problem.

When I apply a tint color to `UISegmentedControl` using something like...

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
```

It generates this...

[image: Red Tint]

All good, but when I add...

```
UIImageView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
```

it changes to...

[image: Green Tint]

Just to be clear, I have BOTH this lines in my code

```
UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.red
UIImageView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
```

It doesn't matter in what order I call them, the result is the same, the `UIImageView` properties override the `UISegmentedControl`s

I've spent over half a day trying to find a solution to this problem but can't seem to find anything that works.

Running Xcode 8.2, iOS 10, Swift 3

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix?

Comment: @PuneetSharma I haven't had a chance to try setting the appearance images yet, on my todo list, just want to know if I was doing something stupid first :P

Comment: I tested it on storyboard and it worked.  I guess, it was not you who was being stupid but appearance API's are ought to be challenging like all global scope things are. It is simple to use but difficult to predict.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but I guess, `UISegmentedControl` uses `UIImageView` to create segments, i.e. the segments we see inside segmented control are `UIImageViews` and not `UIViews`. `UISegmentedControl` even has methods to setImage for a particular segment.

If above is true, we can use appearanceWhenContainedIn API of `UIAppearance` to set image view tint colour like this:

```
UIImageView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISegmentedControl.self]).tintColor = UIColor.red
UIImageView.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: Ohh, nice idea, I'll give it a shot when I get home!

Comment: Yep, works great, that saves me a LOT of effort! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!!